How to generate biased random walks from data?
Imagine I have data (as a list of lists) of the following kind, where I am tracking the positions of specific object centroids over time (independent form each other, so the initial location does not really matter)

I want to use this sample to find a way of generating a random path that resembles this distributions (say, starting from higher x values). What is the best way to do this? This is almost like a biased random walk.
Initially I tried to model the movements of centroids by fitting a Gaussian distribution to the steps between consecutive positions. This involves calculating the average step and the variability in both x and y directions, which captures the typical movement patterns. By doing this, I can generate new centroid paths by starting from an initial position and iteratively sampling steps from the fitted Gaussian distribution, ensuring that these new paths statistically resemble the observed movements in the original data. However, I am not getting near what I need

Any ideas?

Your model doesn't seem to be a great description of what's going on in your data, which is why the simulations look different. In particular it looks to me like many of your actual centroid movements may have a change in their directional bias (first strongly ↗, then slightly less strongly ↘), rather than the increments being homogeneous in time. You're picking up the average of those, which is the drift to the right, and weakly up that you see in your simulations.
